# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I can't fix this error. Won't you help me.This error occurs when I install PyAudio.

Error processing line 7 of d:\python\lib\site-packages\pywin32.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "d:\python\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
      exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32_bootstrap'

```
 Remainder of file ignored
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnecti
on object at 0x000001C3C2DE98B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed')': /simple/pyaudio/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnecti
on object at 0x000001C3C2DF7AC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed')': /simple/pyaudio/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnecti
on object at 0x000001C3C2DF7730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed')': /simple/pyaudio/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnecti
on object at 0x000001C3C2DF7460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed')': /simple/pyaudio/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 
connection 
broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnecti
on object at 0x000001C3C2DF75B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed')': /simple/pyaudio/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio
```

Comment: What code snippet are you trying to run? No one can help you with just traceback of some random error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please go through this and edit your question accordingly so that others can help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try `pip install PyAudio=0.2.11`

Answer (score 1):

Solution of PyAudio Installation Failed Error on Windows:

Firstly open cmd or terminal on windows. Then write this command: pip install pipwin

It may take some time to install this. After install pipwin, write this command: pipwin install pyaudio

I hope your problem will be solved.